# Unable to check hidden custom checkbox

Tags: testing, automation, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

I have tried many options, but not successful so far to click on checkbox that are custom checkboxes with :before tag and are hidden. Can someone show me the way to resolve this issue. I tried X-Path and other selector, it finds and clicks on those checkboxes but those checkboxes don't get checked for some reason.

```html
<fieldset class="checkbox">
                <legend>Services</legend>

                <ul class="multiColumnList">
                    <li><label for="AccountUsers_0__ViewOrders"><input data-val="true" data-val-required="The View Orders field is required." id="AccountUsers_0__ViewOrders" name="AccountUsers[0].ViewOrders" type="checkbox" value="true" class="hidden-field"><span class="custom checkbox"></span><input name="AccountUsers[0].ViewOrders" type="hidden" value="false">View Orders</label></li>
```

[Here is the screenshot of HTML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/svPSK.png)

Answer (score 2):

Try to click on the checkbox in the following way:

```js
const checkboxSelector = Selector('#AccountUsers_0__ViewOrders');
const labelSelector = Selector('[for="AccountUsers_0__ViewOrders"]')

await t.click(labelSelector);
await t.expect(checkboxSelector.checked).ok();
```

If this does not help, let me know. I will find a suitable solution for you.

Comment: This is how they have designed this page. I talked to Dev once, but he was little reluctant to do anything about it.

Comment: That doesn't work because it has hidden type. Testcafe is able to locate it, but complains that it's hidden and can't be clicked. There is a custom checkbox with :before tag (I have attached screenshot above), and that also doesn't work for some reason. Is there a way to click on that?

Comment: The input element with the `AccountUsers_0__ViewOrders` id doesn't have the `hidden` type and this element isn't placed in 'before'. It has the `checkbox` type. This means that you can click on this element without any problem.

Comment: That input element has a class="hidden-field". I have tried that before and it doesn't work. 
I heard someone mention about manipulating this on client side, unhiding the element and check it. I haven't done anything like that before, so I don't know. Do you know if that can be done. If yes, can you show me an example please.

Comment: Tried the new selector and didn't work. I didn't get any error for that selector, but the mouse pointer was clicking very far from the actual label. And got this error below, obviously because checkbox was not checked.

 1) AssertionError: expected false to be truthy

I tried this selector that at least click on that checkbox but the checkbox doesn't get checked.

const labelSelector = Selector('fieldset > ul > li:first-child [class="custom checkbox"]');

Got the exact same error as above for this one too for assertion.  Hope there is some way to make this work.

Comment: Ok, I need a full example. Please create [a new issue](https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/new?assignees=&labels=TYPE%3A+bug&template=bug_report.yaml) and try to fill all fields.

Answer (score 1):

```
   async Check() {
    const checkboxSelector = Selector(`[id="AccountUsers_0__ViewOrders"]`)
                             .with({visibilityCheck: true});
    if(!checkboxSelector.checked){
      await t.click(checkboxSelector);  
    }
    
    await t.expect(checkboxSelector.checked).eql(true, 'Should be checked')
  }

  async UnCheck() {
    const checkboxSelector = Selector(`[id="AccountUsers_0__ViewOrders"]`)
                             .with({visibilityCheck: true});
    if(checkboxSelector.checked){
      await t.click(checkboxSelector);
    }

    await t.expect(checkboxSelector.checked).eql(false, 'Should be unchecked')
  }
```

Please try this code and let me know

Comment: Thanks Surya. I tried the code above and It's failing at this step with error below:

 await t.expect(checkboxSelector.checked).eql(true, 'Should be checked')
---
 1) AssertionError: Should be checked: expected false to deeply equal true

      + expected - actual

      -false
      +true